# Fitting a 2d Gaussian with data points on python

Tags: image-processing, data-fitting

I have an 2048x2048 image/array with some blobs and I try to fit a 2D gaussian on each blob to find its width. [Image with blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/augAc.jpg)

I know the position of the blobs, their intensity and an approximation of the blob rays.
What can I do?

All the codes that I found need the gaussin width...

thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the DAOStarFinder? It returns a sharpness. It is stated: "The sharpness statistic measures the ratio of the difference between the height of the central pixel and the mean of the surrounding non-bad pixels in the convolved image, to the height of the best fitting Gaussian function at that point." So looking at the source code you could get directly hand on that Gaussian. The whole thing, however, assumes that your image is convoluted with a Gaussian detector function. So you have to set a value there. Later you can consider this value, when analyzing the results.